# Creating a virtualizing listview in metro xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I need to create a listview that is bound to items that are loaded when the user scrolls to the beginning or end of the list. I've seen the ISupportIncrementalLoading interface, but this only supports loading in one direction (forward / more). Is it possible to load in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possibility for you, but I have acieved a solution to this kind of problem by inserting new items into the `ListView.Items` collection at index 0

Comment: Thanks Dean, our issue is not so much the data loading, but the detection of when the user scrolls past the end of the data. I might give something like http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/RefreshBox-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx a go over the next few days